# How to pass a C# UIViewController to a C function receiving a UIViewController *

Tags: c#, marshalling

UPDATED: Answer below.

I have a static C library that receives a UIViewController, it then uses that View Controller to present it's own UIViewController, take control and display some UI, then release. I am having problems figuring out how to bind / marshall my UIViewController from C# to that C function.

My C# code make a class like this:

using System; using System.Collections.Specialized; using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
 namespace ImportedUI 
 { 

      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

      public class MyUI
      {
          [DllImport("__Internal")]
          protected extern static void MyUIInit(ref MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController viewController);

          public MyUI(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController viewController)
          {
               MyUIInit(ref viewController);
          }
      }
 }
```

My Static Library function define is:

void MyUIInit(UIViewController *viewController);

The above gets a marshalling exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
public class MyUI
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    protected extern static void MyUIInit(IntPtr viewController);

    public MyUI(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController viewController)
    {
        MyUIInit(viewController.Handle);
    }
}
```